# Какой WYSIWYG редактор лучше всего использовать для проекта?

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, php, javascript, веб-программирование

С тех что есть знаю:

`"TinyMCE"` - как я понимаю в нем могут быть заморочки с добавлением своего функционала.

`"jQuery redactor"` от imperavi - увы, почему-то стал платным, хотя он у меня в фаворе если чсн.

`"MarkitUp"` - в одном из комментов на хабре читал что он исп. фреймы, не знаю как вам, но мне это не очень нравится.

`"CKEditor"` - не пробовал.

А в итоге хотелось бы легкий в весе и такой в функционале.

Comment: Я бы этот взял, все-таки бутстрап внушает доверие http://habrahabr.ru/post/176897/

Comment: Если возможно выбирайте бутстрап (как указал выше @deniz)+ filemanager - ом(чтоб картинки загрузить), если нет , то можно CKEditor, как в раз сейчась у нее тема бутстрапа+ можно самому без каких либо плагинов uploader написать . Этот вариант я использую в своих проектах.

Answer (score 4):

Сам сейчас использую **imperavi** - 100 баксов - не деньги, а поддержка у них весьма адекватная - ошибки исправляют и высылают новые версии своевременно.

Долгое время использовал "CKEditor" и "TinyMCE" - сейчас считаю их просто перегруженными бесполезным функционалом монстрами. Про "MarkitUp!" ничего не скажу - не привлекает.

Comment: а на тарифе за 100 баксов есть ограничения по кол-ву сайтов?

Comment: Нет, там ключевые условия - нельзя редактор продавать просто как редактор, и нельзя устанавливать его в бесплатно распространяемые продукты.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо за инфу!

Comment: $400, если скрипт бесплатный, например GPL. Жаль. Дорого.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вот: http://www.aloha-editor.org/

Подключал его, проблем с этим не было, но некоторые баги случались (это около года назад было).

Ставил рядом CKEditor, который, кстати, тоже в iframe подгружается. Не вижу в этом ничего плохого (или MarkitUp подгружает прямо frameset — от этого негодование?).

Answer (score 1):

У Imperavi оплаченная ORM лицензия для yii. Так что если вы собираетесь использовать данный фреймворк, то за Imperavi платить не придется. Но я бы посоветовал Вам CKEditor или TinyMCE (очень много расширений можно найти и без проблем поставить).